# Any support in Spring Batch for reading multiple files under zip

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I am looking for loading people records from multiple files based on location. Is there any easy support by Spring batch to load multiple files named location weise?
Easy Country_people.zip
-> Location1 (folder1) containing 3 text files(people_education.txt, people_address.txt, people_income.txt)

```
 -> Location2 (folder2) containing 3 text files(people_education.txt, people_address.txt, people_income.txt)

 -> Location3 (folder3) containing 3 text files(people_education.txt, people_address.txt, people_income.txt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `Partitioner` to get the data from multiple files

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning

Or https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemReader.html

```java
public class CustomMultiResourcePartitioner implements Partitioner {
 
    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> map = new HashMap<>(gridSize);
        int i = 0, k = 1;
        for (Resource resource : resources) {
            ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
            Assert.state(resource.exists(), "Resource does not exist: " 
              + resource);
            context.putString(keyName, resource.getFilename());
            context.putString("opFileName", "output"+k+++".xml");
            map.put(PARTITION_KEY + i, context);
            i++;
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```